# What kind of a destructor does Rhapsody generate?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, rhapsody

I'm starting to learn how to use Rhapsody, and I drew the following model:

[image: model]

I switched to `Active code view` selected the class A, and in the `A.cpp` file I had the following:

```
A::~A() {
    cleanUpRelations();
}

void A::cleanUpRelations() {
    if(itsB != NULL)
        {
            itsB = NULL;
        }
}
```

Wouldent this behavior create a memory leak?

(the rhapsody version is 7.6, running on Win server 2008)

Comment: If itsB is a managed pointer then this will free a reference and clean up if its the last reference. Can you see its declaration ?

Comment: @Kindread yes, I can see it's declaration:  `B* itsB;`

Comment: oh looks like a raw pointer :P. Then possibly A isn't retaining ownership of itsB, but is only keeping a pointer to it. Is itsB allocated within A's code, or is itsB set to something that is passed in in one of A's constructors or functions ?

Comment: @Kindread good point - `itsB` is never allocated in the A class.